# rspec: how to test redis publish

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec3

I'm using the 'realtime' gem for realtime message.

Given something like(code from offical website)

```
# if using redis:
$redis.publish 'realtime_msg', {msg: 'hello world - ' + SecureRandom.hex, recipient_user_ids: [41, 42]}.to_json
```

How can I test this code with rspec?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a spy to `$redis` to assert that `publish` gets called with certain arguments like so:

```
expect($redis).to receive(:publish).with('realtime_msg', /hello world/)`
```

The last part, `/hello world.*recipient_user_ids/` is just an example of a regular expression you could use to match the JSON string you're providing as a second argument to `publish`. You could use a custom matcher there or any other rspec argument matcher that serves your purpose.